# Using C++-AMP to reduce runtime of unsorted vector search

Tags: c++, c++-amp

I have written a program that does a lot of searching through an unsorted vector of struct to find indices of unique elements. This searching is done multiple times each iteration in a for-loop and also the data inside the vector changes multiple times during the for-loop iteration (data is only added, nothing is removed). Now the program does what I want it to do, but it is rather slow, so after I let VS2012 analyze the performance of my program I found that more than 80% of the time the program is searching through the unsorted vector, so naturally I want to optimize the searching. I know the best I can get is O(n), because it is an unsorted vector (every element is unique and the order of the elements cannot change once they are inserted), but I am hoping to reduce the runtime somehow.

I've been thinking of using parallel processing to reduce the programs runtime and Microsoft's AMP library looks promising. By the looks of it you can use parallel processing to iterate through an array to find an element in the array. But the data in the unsorted vector changes a lot, so won't this move the bottleneck from iterating the vector to data transfer from CPU to GPU or has AMP build-in optimizations to cope with this? Remember: the data in the vector is only added at the end of the vector, nothing is removed.

Just in case it helps: here is the vector and the search function I use:

```
struct VertexData
{
    VertexData( unsigned int pos, unsigned int norm, unsigned int tex )
        : posIdx(pos), normIdx(norm), texIdx(tex) {}

    unsigned int posIdx;
    unsigned int normIdx;
    unsigned int texIdx;

    inline bool operator<( const VertexData &rhs ) const
    {
        return std::tie(posIdx, normIdx, texIdx) < std::tie(rhs.posIdx, rhs.normIdx, rhs.texIdx);
    }

    inline bool operator==( const VertexData &rhs ) const
    {
        return std::tie(posIdx, normIdx, texIdx) == std::tie(rhs.posIdx, rhs.normIdx, rhs.texIdx);
    }
};

std::vector<VertexData> verts;

int findIndex( const std::vector<VertexData> &vec, const VertexData &val ) const
{
    std::vector<VertexData>::const_iterator it;
    int idx = 0;
    for ( it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it, ++idx )
        if ( *it == val )
            return idx;

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to maintain an index and an iterator during the iteration. I would simply use `auto it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), val); return it == vec.end()? -1: (it - vec.begin());` However, I don't expect that change to make a huge impact.

Comment: You could maintain two data structures, the one you have now for order and another for retrieval.

Comment: What is stopping you from maintaining some kind of lookup index, or rearranging the array?  What exactly is your algorithm designed to do?

Comment: Any chance you can use a [std::multiset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) in place of your vector ? Or a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` if the values are unique ? It would require your handling code us an iterator rather than an index, and you couldn't keep them between insertions as they would become invalid, but your search time would be significantly improved.

Comment: @paddy the algorithm processes parsed Wavefront OBJ model data. At the end of the for-loop the vector contains a set of unique vertex coordinates where the indices of the elements in that vector are used in a index buffer. The index buffer is filled at the same time the vector is filled, so that's why I cannot rearrange the array..

Comment: @WhozCraig I've thought of that, but the position of the elements cannot change after they are put into the vector so the array cannot be rearranged. I can do it however, if I iterate all the data twice (i.e. create a second for-loop), but I was hoping to avoid that..

Comment: @GManNickG Oh wow, can't believe I didn't think of that. That simple solution might actually work

Comment: @KrienLinnenbank So what's stopping you from also storing an index lookup such as a `std::map<VertexData, int>`?

Comment: @paddy Yes, that is exactly what I'm going to do. Can't believe I didn't think of this earlier. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use something like boost::multi-index array to hold a sorted unique set of indices to your unsorted vector? That way you avoid the extra work each time.

Algorithmic fixes are always better than brute force, as a rule.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but I recon you mean more or less the same as posted in the comments above, so I'll mark this as the solution. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I was suggesting that you could use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html
This allows you to contruct a sorted view of your unsorted data. If however you do not need more than one ordering, then the comment suggesting std::multiset is a better solution, as its simpler.